# not able to send message to remote Tomcat and ActiveMQ queue

Tags: jms, tomcat7, activemq-classic

I have a set of JMS queues configured on a Tomcat + ActiveMQ server. I have created a Resource for connectionFactory (by pointing the Broker to tcp:localhost:61616) and a resource for Queue in Server.xml inside global resource and then declared these 2 resource as  in context.xml.

Now I'm trying to connect this queue from another tomcat server and send message.  When trying to get lookup for connection factory with jndi name I am getting NamingException - name not bound in this context for the ConnectionFactory JNDI.

I tried to achieve like this:
set below values in properties
    Provider_URL = http://Localhost:8080
    INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory

and then create new InitialContext with above property value and then lookup for the jndi of connectionFactory.

But its not working.

I tried other option to directly get context of the ActiveMQ by using ActiveMQContextFactory as INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY and Provider_URL= tcp://localhost:61616
and I kept a simple jndi.properties file in the classpath of client tomcat server as it is mentioned in other posts. And It works well.

But I do not like it. Because when I configured the activeMQ connection and Queue as a resource in Tomcat, that means I should be able to get JNDI lookup through Tomcat and not directly to Active mq. I do not want to give ActiveMQ host:port to all my clients.

I assume there must be something incorrect on Tomcat server configuration that its connectionfactory/queue JNDI is not available for lookup outside.

I have struggle a lot today. Can someone expert point me to some possible mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not very clear from your description what you have done and what needs to be done.  However I would try to see if JNDI is set up correctly at the first place.

Comment: I added details. Please help.